# Is it possible to run head & use nl to number the lines?

Tags: head, nl

When i ran `head file.txt && nl file.txt` it did each command in order of occurance (which makes sense). Is it possible to have the head display with numbered lines, so that this:

```
word
word
word
```

would become this:

```
1 word
2 word
3 word
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
head file.txt | nl
```

The `|` creates a [pipeline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02) that takes the output of `head file.txt` and gives it to `nl` as its "standard" input. Bare `nl` without a file name will read its standard input and number it, so you get the output of `head` numbered as you wanted.

Without a pipe providing input, just

```
nl
```

would read input from the terminal that you typed. The pipe is a way of providing that data as though you'd typed it in like that.

You can pipe from any command that prints its output, and pipe to any command that reads from the terminal like that, and even pipe several things together:

```
head -n 50 file.txt | nl | tail -n 20
```

will give you numbered lines 31-50 from the file.